# R not loading packages on some MAC versions

Tags: r

I am using the regular R console on a MAC Air with Monterrey as the OS and I'm still having issues loading packages. It is iffy, as to whether a package is loaded and ready to use. Sometimes packages will load and sometimes not. Also, it would not call up data sets that as a default are included in the R packages I'm trying to use. the weird thing is it would recognize the example dataset that is included because when I first tied to call them up, it would let me autocomplete the name. Then it stopped doing that. Then it started telling me that the file doesn't exist. I know I haven't used R in a while but this just seems buggy! any help would be appreciated.

The R version that I have installed is : R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics" and it was installed just last week.

Comment: What are the error messages that you get? You can use `installed.packages()` to see which packages are installed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems R was not properly installed on your machine.

Several persons reported that using the package manager in RStudio actually did the trick of updating the packages.